# Pulseaudio uses 100% CPU and eats RAM after suspend if Rhythmbox is stopped

Tags: suspend, pulseaudio, rhythmbox

I have a weird problem with Ubuntu 16.04. When waking up the computer from suspend, sometimes (about 1/3 of the cases), pulseaudio starts using 100% CPU (on one thread) and allocating huge chunks of memory (gigabyte in less than a minute). I have to kill it to prevent Ubuntu from killing other processes to get more RAM for it.

It appears to be somehow related to Rhythmbox, because Rhythmbox has huge memory usage too if this happens (it appears to increase with pulseaudio's memory usage) and every time it happened, Rhythmbox' playback was stopped, done playing the listed music.

EDIT: It is still a problem on Ubuntu 18.04 and seems to happen even with some other players than Rhythmbox. It does *not* appear with cmus.